# Dynamically create multiple Firebase references using a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, firebase

I am writing a script that uses Firebase to interact with a dashboard of pin values on my Raspberry Pi. It also allows me to update those pin values via firebase. I've managed to create a dynamic script that works with any given number of pins, but the one part I'm having trouble with is how to dynamically create the actual firebase references themselves. For example;

If I want to reference the first 9 pins, I have this in my script to create the 9 references;

```
var myFirebaseRef1 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/1");
var myFirebaseRef2 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/2");
var myFirebaseRef3 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/3");
var myFirebaseRef4 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/4");
var myFirebaseRef5 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/5");
var myFirebaseRef6 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/6");
var myFirebaseRef7 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/7");
var myFirebaseRef8 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/8");
var myFirebaseRef9 = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/9");
```

How can I stick that lot into a loop and avoid having 10 repeated lines? I've tried using the EVAL function, Arrays etc, but none have worked?! I've managed to 'variablize' every aspect of the script bar this bit!

Answer (score 0):

You can store each Ref in an array like so, for instance

```
var fires = {};
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    fires["myFirebaseRef" + i] = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/" + i);
}
```

or globally in the `window` var:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    window["myFirebaseRef" + i] = new Firebase("https://ant-torch-2.firebaseio.com/gpio2/" + i);
}
```

and access each ref like so:

```
console.log(myFirebaseRef1);
```

but then it will be globally available. you might not want this when working with closures/ scopes.

Comment: Perfect :) The first option still gave me an error, but the second option worked just as I needed, thanks!